# Zooming in to area using Copernicus Open Access Hub?

Tags: zoom, sentinel-2, copernicus, esa, sentinel-hub

I can pan but I cannot zoom in when using the Copernicus Open Access Hub.
This makes it difficult to order data.

I need to know how to zoom in on an area.

I know how to zoom to a product.

Copernicus Open Access Hub.

https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/GraphicalUserInterface

This interface. I see Pan but not zoom.
[image: The user interface]

Comment: For me, scrolling the mouse controls the zoom.

Comment: @jon ahh i have no mouse usually.... Ill try that. so simple.

Comment: No mouse? Impressive that you can use a computer these days without one.

Comment: Same issue two years latter. Would be great to have keyboard's shortcuts for that.
@jon: it is call a "touchpad". Some of them does not have scrolling abilities.